# How can I solve jupyter lab dependency issues when installing an extension?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-widget

I'm trying a new Python lib, and the docs tell to install a jupyter lab extension to make it work, using the command:

> jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@2

However, there is some kind of conflict. I have no idea how to solve it... The log file is not helpful to me.

[image]

Comment: Do you need jupyterlab-manager@2.0.0? If please do not constrict the version so it will be compatible with other extensions.

Comment: Which version of JupyterLab are you using? You may not need to install `@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager` at all since it is [shipped as a prebuilt extension](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html#installing-in-jupyterlab-3-0)  - i.e. auto-installed when you do `pip install "ipywidgets>=7.6"` - since version 7.6 of ipywidgets (if this is what you aim to achieve).